# Django - How to sett a variable on layout template and use it across all views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to set a variable and display it on the top navigation. I would like to do a count of received email and display the number on the menu informing the user they have eg 3 messages.

Just as you can access your user id or username I want to access the count of the email the user received.

I was checking how to set global variables but there might be something else I can do. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: is Email a model itself? How do you derive the count by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a context processor:

**myapp/processor.py**

```
def add_email_count(request):
   context = {
      'email_count': request.user.email_count(),
      'exemple_list': [44, 55, 99]
   }
   return context
```

**settings.py**, add the path of your processor in context_proceesors:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
         ... 
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ....
                'myapp.processor.add_email_count'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and you can get it in all template :

```
{{ email_count }}

{% for number in exemple_list %}
  {{ number }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you for tihs , this is what i did in settings.py TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].append("accounts.context_processors.categories_processor") is your suggestion better ?

Comment: normaly TEMPLATES settings key is defined in top of file , with other django's processors, and template configuration.  look doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/

Answer (score 1):

Within your view you can define a [`session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) variable in your view to allow you to use across all view. For example:

**views.py**

```py
request.sessions['received_email_count'] = 1
```

When navigating to your next view you can increment this number like so:

```py
request.sessions['received_email_count'] += 1
```

This session variable can be used in the template like so:

**template.html**

```html
{{ request.session.recieved_email_count }}
```